# Modifying Google Chrome a bit

Tags: google-chrome, chromium-embedded

I want to make some modifications to the Chrome browser:

- Tab bar UI and behavior
- Session/tab storage behavior

I still want to retain everything else.

What's the easiest way to make a browser that only differs in those two aspects?
I do not want to mess with Javascript/GPU/PDF support etc. I only want to tweak the behavior slightly.

I've never modified browsers. I do not know how close to Chrome are CEF or the multitude of Chromium-based browsers.

Should I use CEF? Should I start with some Chromium-based open-source browser?

Comment: Your question's *far* too broad..

Answer (score 0):

`CEF` is framework for embedding `Chromium` into an existing application. It doesn't provide any `UI` elements like `Back/Forward/Stop` etc. So you would have to effectively write the `UI` yourself and implement the required features. There are `CEF` wrappers for a multitude of languages, `Python`, `.Net`, `Java`.

See https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/Tutorial for some more info on building an app with `CEF` in `C++`

If you wish to simply modify the `UI` and make a few other tweaks then I'd probably look at forking an existing project.

(For a more specific answer then you'll need to update your question with some details of what your actually trying to achieve, what languages your familiar with etc.)